# What is the fastest way to do this PHP/SQL/Sort

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, time

So the database structure I have is:

```
steamid | mapname | name | teleports | runtime | runetimepro | teleports_pro
```

[image]

So what I need to do is for each map I need to figure out a player's rank among others who have run that map. Players can either run a map with a protime (runtimepro) or a normal time (runtime). So if a play has both a protime and a normal time then I would have to know his rank for both protime and normal time (they are independent of each other).

My current method for doing this is to have a foreach loop that loops through each mapname and sends the player's steamid, mapname and run type to a function and then queries a database. The code for that is below:

```
function getKZTimeRank($steamID, $map, $type, $dbkz){
    if($type == "Pro"){
        $stmt = "SELECT * From playertimes WHERE mapname = :mapname AND runtimepro <> -1 ORDER BY runtimepro DESC";
        $query = $dbkz->prepare($stmt);
        $query->bindValue(":mapname", $map);
        $query->execute();
        $items = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count = 1;
        foreach($items as $map){
            if ($map['steamid'] == $steamID){
                return $count;
            }else{
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }elseif($type == "TP"){
        $stmt = "SELECT * From playertimes WHERE mapname = :mapname AND runtime <> -1 ORDER BY runtime DESC";
        $query = $dbkz->prepare($stmt);
        $query->bindValue(":mapname", $map);
        $query->execute();
        $items = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count = 1;
        foreach($items as $map){
            if ($map['steamid'] == $steamID){
                return $count;
            }else{
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code grabs only the map we are looking for and all the times for that map (either pro or normal which is determined by `$type`) and pulls those in descending order. With those sorted players by map, it will search for the steamid with a counter and return the position it finds the player in. This works and works fairly quick for small sets of data but I am trying to list a players times by map and there are a couple hundred maps and a couple thousand players. The script is taking a bit of time to run since it requires a query to be run for each map the player has run. There is an outer loop that gets all the maps a player has run and also gets the times for the maps, this function then finds where that time would place among other times. So for my profile, for instance, I have completed 190 maps so for each map, it has to run this function a minimum of 1 times. Some maps require it to be run twice if I have both a pro and normal time. So minimum I perform 190 queries (plus 1 outside query) at maximum 380 (plus 1) queries. This script for me only takes 6.5 seconds or so but for other players, it takes 12 to 15 seconds. Is there a better way to do this? I've looked into array_multisort() but I am not sure if that would benefit this project. Any help would be nice. Am I doing it in one of the best ways? I can try and rectify any confusion if something is unclear.

Comment: Well if you truly want to know if a version you think of is better than another one, just implement it and look how many ms it takes for each version (make an average, for example run a hundred times the functions and divide by a hundred)

Comment: and what's the structure of your maps table ?

Comment: I thought about multisort but I am still thinking about how I could actually implement it. I know I would have to sort by mapname and protime/normal time but then I am still trying to think of the other loops required to make sure I am staying within that specific map I am looking at and some other specifics. Still trying to figure out the logistics of that method.

Comment: There is no maps table, the way I get the maps is by a query that just selects everything from the `playertime` table where the steamid matches and then I run that through a foreach to get each map. So with that I can generate 90% of the table, mapname, time on that map, teleports, ect... but I can't get the rank from that which is why I have this function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one thing you can try is this :

Get all of one player's informations :

```
SELECT * FROM playertimes WHERE steamid = :steamid and mapname = :mapname
```

And then you can count every times that are before the player time :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as aggregate From playertimes WHERE mapname = :mapname AND runtimepro <> -1 AND runtimepro < :runtimepro
```

and then you have one player's rank :

```
$item = $query->fetch();
$rank = $item->aggregate;
```

The same can be done for the normal runtime

I think it will work but I don't know if it will go faster